# No scroll on a datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is it possible to disable the scrolls and make them invisible on a datagrid?

thank you

Comment: @Sarang I'm not sure what your trying to communicate with your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes!

To solve your problem:  Look at [horizontalScrollPolicy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ScrollControlBase.html#horizontalScrollPolicy) and [verticalScrollPolicy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ScrollControlBase.html#verticalScrollPolicy) .  Set them both to off.

Answer (score 1):

Sarang, do you have any understanding of the difference between Flex and ASP or you just sticking your 50 cents all over no mater what?

@John:

you wont have scrolls if height of the grid calculated right, something like height="{(this.dataProvider.length*gridRowHeight)+10}" plus u can switch off scrolling policies on your grid.